# Does the DLL Plugin do anything when using Webpack@5.x?

Tags: performance, webpack, webpack-5, dllplugin

[The docs still mention the DLL Plugin,](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Q275TzszEeAJ:https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/+&cd=1&hl=en) but in the many months since Webpack 5 has been released I haven't seen anyone who has a working DLL Plugin configuration whenever I look.

Is it no longer compatible? Just not beneficial anymore for performance? I can't figure out what the deal is with this plugin post-Webpack 4.

PS: Linked to Google cache for the docs because webpack.js.org seems to be down at the moment.